# Jquery Qtip Autohide as well as Hide by Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, qtip

How can I tell a JQuery qtip tooltip to hide after it is clicked on "or" when it is inactive for some seconds?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/xffo4mfc/1/

```
$('#wrap a').qtip({

    show: 'mouseover',
    hide: 'mouseout'

}).click(function () {// hide qtip on click event

    $(this).qtip('hide');

})
```